# Pandas to_numeric

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use `pandas.to_numeric()` in order to convert the value of a column in my DataFrame to integers. The DataFrame is as follows:

|  | QuestionID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Q1 | 150.0 |
| 1 | Q2 | 160.0 |
| 2 | Q3 | NaN |
| 3 | Q4 | 210.0 |
| 4 | Q5 | Hello |

How could I possibly convert the values to integers if I have `NaN` and Hello among the values using `pandas.to_numeric()` while also dropping the rows that cannot be converted?

My expected dataframe is as follows:

|  | QuestionID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Q1 | 150 |
| 1 | Q2 | 160 |
| 3 | Q4 | 210 |

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Comment: Do you consider `NaN` as a valid integer?

Answer (score 3):

'coerce' will return NaN for any non numeric value, which you can then drop those records with dropna.

```
df.assign(Value=pd.to_numeric(df.Value, errors='coerce')).dropna()
```

Comment: This removes invalid rows but does not cast the "Value" column to integer (but to float) as OP asked.

Comment: @hyit I'm hoping OP is capable of figuring out the rest

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Q1", "150"], ["Q2", "160"], ["Q3", "NaN"],
                   ["Q4", "210"], ["Q5", "Hello"]], columns=["QuestionID", "Value"])
df

  QuestionID  Value
0         Q1    150
1         Q2    160
2         Q3    NaN
3         Q4    210
4         Q5  Hello
```

Since you'd like to drop all invalid rows, I'd perhaps consider using the `pd.Series.str.isnumeric()` as an indexer:

```
df = df[df["Value"].str.isnumeric()]  # Keep rows with numeric values in "Value"
df.loc[:, "Value"] = df["Value"].astype(int)  # Cast to integers
```

Alternatively, building on [@Chris suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69746617/4133131), you can also add the integer type-casting after the `df.assign` call:

```
df.assign(Value=pd.to_numeric(df["Value"], errors='coerce')).dropna().astype({"Value": int})
```

Comment: your second code returns an error. I believe it is the first curly bracket that does not have a matching closing bracket. Could you please edit the code?

Comment: I ran the code as follows: df.assign(Guess=pd.to_numeric(df.Guess, errors='coerce')).dropna().astype({"Guess": int})   
Unfortunately, I got the column where neither "NaN" nor "Hello" were dropped, and all other values remain as floats

Comment: Sorry, indeed it had an error - thanks for highlighting it - I've fixed it now. Notice that this creates a new dataframe with the updated values, it does not augment `df` in place.